# Clone Sql table automatically from sql

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two exactly same tables. My question:  is there any way when i'm inserting something in first table automatically sql server to copy this row into another table.

I know that i can do it manually

```
select * into table1 from table2 where table2ID=@table2ID
```

But i'm wondering if i can create a table dynamically and set it  when a row is inserted, copy row's data into another table also.
So with this way i dont need to run extra code to do that, sql will do this automatically

Comment: You can look into using a trigger for this.

Comment: have u tried using a trigger?

Comment: I dont know how trigger works.Can i use it in sql 2008?

Comment: Please make the very basic effort of googling "trigger sql 2008"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `TRIGGER` which is an object that you link to a table with a particular operation (`INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE` or any combination of those). The trigger's code will execute on each operation done to the linked table.

Basic example:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.CopyToTable2 ON Table1
    AFTER INSERT -- The trigger will execute after any insert done to Table1
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON

    INSERT INTO Table2 (
        Column1,
        -- OtherColumns
        )
    SELECT
        I.Column1
        -- OtherColumns
    FROM
        inserted AS I -- "inserted" is a special table that references the trigger's tracking table for new or updated records

END
```

Answer (score 0):

The use of a trigger is appropriate here. It might look something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER SomeTriggerName ON theSourceTable
FOR INSERT
AS
INSERT INTO DestinationTable
    (column1, someothercolumn)
SELECT (column1, someothercolumn)
FROM inserted
```